# Service Bus NET Core client (NET Standard client). Unable to connect to on prem servicebus instance

Tags: .net-core, servicebus

I downloaded the code from here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet

and tried try to run the tests but am getting this:
Message: System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.UnitTests.TestUtility' threw an exception.
---- System.ArgumentException : Illegal connection string parameter name 'StsEndpoint'
Parameter name: connectionString

I'm using on premise service bus version. Is this not supposed to be supported?
This is the connection string I use:

Endpoint=sb://hostname.corp.domain.com/ServiceBusEapQANamespace;StsEndpoint=https://hostname.corp.domain.com:9355/ServiceBusEapQANamespace;RuntimePort=9354;ManagementPort=9355;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=bKnerepD9LBGHIVAM4nXJTw5kAAP5updfQYhH2gFG/o=

This same connection string works fine with other tools e.g. Service Bus Explorer

If I remove couple of the "unsupported" parameters and simplify my conn string to this: Endpoint=sb://hostname.corp.domain.com/ServiceBusEapQANamespace;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=bKnerepD9LBGHIVAM4nXJTw5kAAP5updfQYhH2gFG/o=

I get this error: Message: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException : None of the server sasl-mechanisms ([PLAIN,EXTERNAL]) are supported by the client (MSSBCBS).

I've opened an issue on the project's site for this as well

https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the issue you opened, new .Net Core client (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus) only supports SAS authentication, which is not available for on-premises Service Bus.